# With MSVC build tools setup with vscode, how to have the *.obj and .pdb files be generated in separated directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, vscode-tasks

Currently they generate under workspace folder. The built binary successfully builds in `build` folder with my `tasks.json` but how do I achieve the same for the `obj` and `.pdb` files. I tried doing that with /Fo and /Fd but it does not work as in with /Fo it complains about that the `obj` directory is not found and with `/Fd` it shows `"fatal error C1041: cannot open program database 'C:\Projects\learningcpp\obj\vc140.pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS"`

My `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/sdl",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe${fileDirname}\\build\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "/Fd${workspaceFolder}\\obj\\vc140.pdb",
                "/Fo${workspaceFolder}\\obj\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.obj",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I tried adding the `/Fo` and `/Fd` arguments. They resulted in errors. I did successfully made it so the generated binary is created in the `build` directory.

Comment: Did you try what the compiler told you to do? `if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS` documentation: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fs-force-synchronous-pdb-writes?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fs-force-synchronous-pdb-writes?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @drescherjm Yes and I still get the same error? The problem as far as I figured out was that unlike `/Fe`, `/Fd` does not create the `out` directory as required. So manually creating it does fixes this. Issue is if I try to write a dependency task to check-if-not-create the directories and use it, I still somehow get back the same errors even if the directories are built.